# Как спроектировать таблицы базы данных?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, проектирование

Делаю бота для телеграм. Хочу записывать все диалоги, которые ведёт бот в лог. Если бы и пользователь, и бот общались только текстовыми сообщениями, то я создал бы таблицу `messages` cо столбцами типа `id`, `text`, `from`, `previous_msg`, `date`, `chat_id`. Но дело в том, что и бот, и пользователь могут отправить не только текст, но и файлы, контакты, стикеры, геоточку и т. д.

Вопрос: есть ли какой то стандарт или просто лучшее с точки зрения удобства и скорости работы решение, которое описывает как распределить данные по таблицам? Я вижу 2 стула:

1. Создать в той же таблице enum поле `msg_type` и добавить поля типа `text`, `file_path`, `caption`, `file_size`, `emoji`, `longitude`, `latitude`... Здесь минус в том, будут заполнены только некоторые из этих полей в зависимости от типа файла, а остальные просто останустся пустыми и по сути будут являться ненужными, то есть лишняя память.
2. Опять создать enum поле с типом, но вместо того, чтобы пихать всё в одну таблицу, разбить на несколько. То есть в основную таблицу добавить столбец `msg_content_id` и создать таблицу для каждого типа: `text_messages`, `contacts`, `locations`, `documents`, 'stickers', 'photos'... Тут я вижу минус, что много таблиц, сложно связывать их в одном запросе. Вероятно будет медленне работать, чем первый вариант.

Какое решение вы бы выбрали? Почему? Есть ли другие подходы?

СУБД PostgreSQL.

Comment: Вариант 3. Использовать [наследование таблиц](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html)

Comment: Посмотрите на структуру объекта Message в документации к Telegram API. Почему бы вам не заимствовать у них структуру этой сущности, при необходимости удалив или добавив некоторые поля? Как минимум это упростит конвертацию в ваш формат. Ссылка на документацию:https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message Как вы можете видеть там некоторые поля опциональные. Но ведь есть nullы, так что это тоже не проблема

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко да, так и сделал

Answer (score 0):

в основную таблицу добавить столбец msg_content_id

...и создать еще одну таблицу "messageContentType" в которой будут
msg_content_id
messageType со значениями text_messages, contacts, locations, documents и т.д...

Соответственно, связками по id будете знать, какого типа у вас контент в основной таблице...

как-то так...

Comment: Почему именно так?

Comment: Потому что в первом варианте возникнет избыточность данных...

Comment: Зачем вам лишние поля, которые могут не использоваться?

Comment: Разве здесь они не переносятся в таблицу messageContentType?

Answer (score 0):

> много таблиц, сложно связывать их в одном запросе

А в чём сложность?

```
SEELCT m.id, COALESCE(s1.body, s2.body, ...) body, ...
FROM maintable m
LEFT JOIN slavetable1 s1 ON (m.slavetype = 1 AND m.slaveref = s1.id)
LEFT JOIN slavetable2 s2 ON (m.slavetype = 2 AND m.slaveref = s2.id)
-- ...
```

> Вероятно будет медленнее работать

При наличии индексов - вряд ли сильно  медленнее. Хотя перекапываемый объём вроде бы больше - так что скорость меньше... но с другой стороны индексы-то компактнее.

Впрочем, быть такого не может, чтобы постгресс не знал о существовании разреженных таблиц и не имел средств работы с ними. Проверь. Если по этой части всё в порядке - наверное, первый "стул" всё же предпочтительнее.